# Unable to retrieve metadata for

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This should be a simple, straight forward issue for the experts to solve, but I am unable to figure this out.

Downloaded VS 2012.  Running through the "Contoso University Web Application" online tutorial on ASP.NET website.  This is working with MVC4 and EF5.

When I get to the part in lesson 1 to create a controller, I get the follow error:

"Unable to retrieve metadata for 'ContosoUniversity.Models.Course'.  Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Objects.ObjectsContextOptions.set_UserConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Booleon)'.

Basically, I cannot create any controller without getting this error.  I felt like I followed the download process and the tutorial correctly.  But there is some kind of bug.

Here is the connection string that I am using straight out of the lesson:

```
<
add name="SchoolContext" 
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ContosoUniversity.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>
```

The model is this:

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Course
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The SchoolContext is this:

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Plz add this section to the entityFramework element in the web.config file; MVC scaffolding will use this type to find ur database context.
If u r using a database initializer to load test data to ur DB, it has to be added as below.

```
<entityFramework>
  <contexts>
    <context type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext, ContosoUniversity">
      <databaseInitializer type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolInitializer, ContosoUniversity" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
<entityFramework>
```